# React Native bundle hangs on CircleCI build, but not with SSH

Tags: react-native, circleci, fastlane

I am running a setup with CircleCI and Fastlane to build Android sdk and push it to an internal S3-bucket. When Fastlane is running in CircleCI, the build freezes, and terminates after 10 minutes (`Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded`). I have also tried increasing the limit in CircleCI to 30m, but it exceeded that deadline as well.

Excerpt from relevant Fastfile:

```
platform :android do
  lane :staging do
    sh "yarn env-staging"
    sh "yarn bundle-android"
    gradle(
      task: "assembleReleaseStaging",
      project_dir: "android/",
      flags: "-x bundleReleaseStagingJsAndAssets"
    )
    aws_s3(
      # All of these are used to make Shenzhen's `ipa distribute:s3` command
      access_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               # Required from user.
      secret_access_key: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY", # Required from user.
      bucket: "MyBucket",                       # Required from user.
      region: "eu-west-1",                       # Required from user.

      apk: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/releaseStaging/myapp-releaseStaging.apk',

      path: "v#{ENV['CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM']}/",
      upload_metadata: true,                          # Upload version.json, plist and HTML. Set to false to skip uploading of these files.
      version_file_name: 'app_version.json',          # Name of the file to upload to S3. Defaults to 'version.json'
      version_template_path: 'path/to/erb'            # Path to an ERB to configure the structure of the version JSON file
    )
  end
end
```

And circleci config.yaml

```yaml
version: 2
jobs:
  build-android-staging:
    working_directory: ~/my-app
    docker:
      - image: cimg/android:2023.02.1-node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - yarn-cache-v1-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - bundle-v1-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - app-node_modules-v1-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "patches.hash" }}
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - run:
          name: patch-package hash
          command: md5sum patches/* > patches.hash
      - save_cache:
          key: yarn-cache-v1-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths: node_modules
      - save_cache:
          key: app-node_modules-v1-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "patches.hash" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Compile typescript files
          command: yarn build
      - run: mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME}
      - run: 
          name: Fastlane bundle
          command: |
            export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gems # Setting specific GEM_HOME due to permissions on bundle install
            bundle install
            bundle exec fastlane android staging
      - save_cache:
          key: bundle-v1-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build-android-staging
```

When running the android staging lane from CircleCI, the build freezes with the following output:

```
[⠋]  [⠙]  [⠹]  [⠸]  [⠼]  [⠴]  [⠦]  [✔]  
+------------------------+---------+--------+
|               Used plugins                |
+------------------------+---------+--------+
| Plugin                 | Version | Action |
+------------------------+---------+--------+
| fastlane-plugin-aws_s3 | 2.1.0   | aws_s3 |
+------------------------+---------+--------+

[07:35:24]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[07:35:24]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[07:35:24]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[07:35:24]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[07:35:24]: ------------------------------
[07:35:24]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[07:35:24]: ------------------------------
[07:35:24]: Driving the lane 'android staging' 
[07:35:24]: ------------------------------
[07:35:24]: --- Step: yarn env-staging ---
[07:35:24]: ------------------------------
[07:35:24]: $ yarn env-staging
[07:35:24]: ▸ yarn run v1.22.19
[07:35:24]: ▸ $ cp config/.env.staging .env
[07:35:24]: ▸ Done in 0.05s.
[07:35:24]: ---------------------------------
[07:35:24]: --- Step: yarn bundle-android ---
[07:35:24]: ---------------------------------
[07:35:24]: $ yarn bundle-android
[07:35:24]: ▸ yarn run v1.22.19
[07:35:24]: ▸ $ react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform android --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
[07:35:25]: ▸ Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
[07:35:25]: ▸ Fast - Scalable - Integrated
+------------------+-----------------+
|            Lane Context            |
+------------------+-----------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios             |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | android         |
| LANE_NAME        | android staging |
+------------------+-----------------+

+------+------------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary               |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                 | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform       | 0           |
| 2    | npm run env-staging    | 0           |
| 3    | npm run bundle-android | 600         |
+------+------------------------+-------------+

[07:45:25]: fastlane finished with errors

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

Re-running the workflow with SSH and running `bundle exec fastlane android staging` from there creates the same freeze, but when I change GEM_HOME and reinstall bundle it will get past the step where it freezes, and exit with a different error code related to the Gradle-build instead.
The CircleCI-build still hangs after this operation.

```bash
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem # Anything works here, as long as it is different from GEM_HOME defined in circleci.yaml
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec fastlane android staging
```

At one time while looking into this, I experienced an error with `[15:53:15]: Exit status of command 'yarn bundle-android' was 137 instead of 0.` in CircleCI indicating a memory issue, but in that case, I would believe the samme memory issues would be consistent with SSH as well.

*Edit*: forgot to add React Native version `0.70.7`, React `18.2.0` and Fastlane `2.212.1`

*Update*:
Pulled the Docker image `2023.02.1-node` to run locally, cloned from GitHub and performed the full pipeline defined in my CircleCI config, and it works first try.
Still no success getting it to work on CircleCI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem, as it seemingly is linked to memory-issues.

Added `resource_class: large` to my config and it now gets past the step where it froze previously.